# SSRS populating empty cells in matrix with previous value 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a matrix with empty cells that I'd like to fill in with the most recent value available.  So forexample I have a report matrix with output looks like:

```
                John         Jim         Tom
1/1/2014         5
1/2/2014         8            1
1/3/2014
1/4/2014                                  6
1/5/2014         11           4           
1/6/2014         
1/7/2014
1/8/2014         15           10          5
```

I'd like it to look like this: * = the value I'd like populated/added

```
                John         Jim         Tom
1/1/2014         5
1/2/2014         8            1
1/3/2014         8*           1*
1/4/2014         8*           1*          7
1/5/2014         11           4           7*
1/6/2014         11*          4*          7*
1/7/2014         11*          4*          7*
1/8/2014         15           10          5
```

I've tried using the Previous function in the [Data] section of the matrix, and it yielded the correct results but only for one day (like this)

```
              John         Jim         Tom
1/1/2014         5
1/2/2014         8            1
1/3/2014         8*           1*
1/4/2014                                  7
1/5/2014         11           4           7*
1/6/2014         11*          4*          
1/7/2014                             
1/8/2014         15           10          5
```

The expression I'm using to get that looks like this:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!RUNNING.Value)),Previous(SUM(Fields!RUNNING.Value)),SUM(Fields!RUNNING.Value))
```

Is this possible to do in SSRS 2008 R2?

Another thing I could do is do it on the database side and loop through and INSERT rows into my dataset for days without data?  But I thought that might be a lot of extra work on the database if I could do it on the SSRS side.  My table looks something like:

```
NAME       DATE          VALUE
John       1/1/2014       5
John       1/2/2014       8
John       1/5/2014       11
John       1/8/2014       15
Jim        1/2/2014       1
Jim        1/5/2014       4
Jim        1/8/2014       10
Tom        1/4/2014       6
Tom        1/8/2014       5
```